# Munin graphs are broken

Tags: linux, debian, munin

My munin graphs all of a sudden display n/a

I tried removing the RRD files, but they still display n/a.

I've run munin-check and it says it's ok.

How do I reset munin or what can cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Start by tailing logs in this order: munin-update.log, munin-graph.log, munin-html.log of the munin server.

I don't think it will be necessary, but here's some additional documentation on it: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq#Q.Thegraphsarenotupdatinganymore

The problem should be pretty clear if you take a look in the logs. Btw, removing the RRDs was probably not the best thing to do :-).

Comment: For me it was the next question below what you posted: http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq#Q.Ihaveinstalledmuninonubuntuserver12.10 even though I'm running 12.04. Weird :)